# warning: unused parameter ‘data’ when creating a new thread

Tags: c, pthreads

```
gcc (GCC) 4.6.3 20120306 (Red Hat 4.6.3-2)
c89
```

Hello,

I am creating a thread to do some work. However, the definition is like this:

```
void *thread_send_fd(void *data)
```

I am creating the thread like this:

```
pthread_create(&thread_send, NULL, thread_send_fd, NULL)
```

However, as I am not actually using the void *data as I am not passing any arguments. I keep getting a warning that I getting fed up with.

```
warning: unused parameter ‘data’ [-Wunused-parameter]
```

I don't want to change my cflags to stop these warnings, as it could prevent a genuine warning.

Any suggestions,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
__attribute__((unused))
```

or

```
(void)varname;
```

Choose whichever is easier for you

Comment: I guess the second. Is the first one portable?

Comment: Yes, some people recommend wrapping it in a macro and having it be UNUSED(varname) but some compilers already export an UNUSED macro but redefining it won't hurt. Personally I think the first is nicer and easier to see than the second.

Comment: Another reason is that it's clearer what your intentions are.

Answer (score 2):

You can shut it up using this somewhere in your function

```
(void)data;
```

Comment: Hello, thanks that worked. However, how does it work? I did try this before data = NULL, but all that does is give me another warning about being set and not used. Thanks.

Comment: @ant2009 It's just syntactic nonsense that tricks the compiler into shutting up without generating code.

Comment: The compiler registers it as a "use" of parameter or variable but past the actual syntax tree building it just removes it since it's do-nothing code.

Answer (score 1):

A thread function doesn't have to take an argument, this prototype is enough:

```
void* thread_send_fd();
```

But if you put parameter into prototype, you should pass a parameter while creating the thread. [Check here](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#PassingArguments) to find out how to pass argument to a thread.

Answer (score 0):

Use C++. Then you can write

```
void func(void *) // unnamed parameter
{
}
```

This is one of the small ways in which the C-like subset of C++ is a better C.

The C methods for suppressing the warning are compiler-specific hacks. The `__attribute__` thing is of course blatantly GCC specific, and there is no requirement anywhere that casting the value of the parameter to `(void)` will shut this up on every compiler.

In some widely ported C code bases you may find the use of macros for this like:

```
UNUSED_PARAM(varname);
```

which are suitably defined for various compilers, e.g.:

```
#define UNUSED_PARAM(X) ((void) X) /* for those compilers where that alone works */
```